# bash- printing two consecutive lines if a pattern found

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to search for a string in a file and print the matching lines together with their next lines in another file.
Example:

input file:

```
>3456/1
A
>1234/2
B
>5678/1
C
>8976/2
D
```

search for: `/2`

output:

```
>1234/2
B
>8976/2
D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -A1 '/2' file
>1234/2
B
--
>8976/2
D
```

From the `man` page:

```
-A num, --after-context=num
             Print num lines of trailing context after each match.
```

You can remove the `--` by piping it to `grep -v '--'` or if you have GNU `grep` then you can simply do:

```
$ grep --no-group-separator -A1 '/2' file
>1234/2
B
>8976/2
D
```

You can re-direct the output of this command to another file.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
sed -n '/\/2/,+1p' file
```

Example:

```
$ sed -n '/\/2/,+1p' file
>1234/2
B
>8976/2
D
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep -A

See the man page:

> ```
>  -A num, --after-context=num
>          Print num lines of trailing context after each match.  See also the -B and -C options.
>  -B num, --before-context=num
>          Print num lines of leading context before each match.  See also the -A and -C options.
> -C[num, --context=num]
>          Print num lines of leading and trailing context surrounding each match.  The default is 2 and is equivalent to -A 2 -B 2.  Note: no whitespace may be given between the option and its argument.
> ```

Here is an example:

```
%grep -A2 /2 input
>1234/2
B
>5678/1
--
>8976/2
D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `grep` the correct tool, but using `awk` you would get:

```
awk '/\/2/ {print $0;getline;print $0}' file
>1234/2
B
>8976/2
D
```

PS you should have found this your self, using goolge.  This is asked many times.

Comment: Why use `getline`? `awk '/\/2/{c=2}c-->0' file`

Comment: @jaypal This will work too.  Why? `getline` is a function in `awk`, and it works fine, but you have to be wear of some pitfalls.  Or you could do: `awk '/\/2/{_=2}_&&_--' file`

Comment: unnecessary use of getline and variables named `_` - gone over to the dark side you have....

Comment: @jaypal - the reason you need `c&&c--` rather than `c-->0` is that the latter will keep decrementing `c` even after it's negative and so in theory if an input file was large enough you could wrap around the size of a signed number and have it appear to be positive again and so start printing the file from that point.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. Thats a great point. I didn't think of that. Appreciate the explanation. `:)`.

Comment: @Jotne - the main reasons not to use getline here are: 1) if in future you need to print 10 lines instead of 2, it requires a complete re-write instead of just replacing `2` with `10`, 2) if you need to add a test to your code to, say, print every line that contains `X` you'd need to add it twice - once in the main body of the script and then again with a test against `$0` after the `getline`, and 3) if you had to process multiple files and had a test for `FNR==1` to do something at the start of each file you could jump over that test as the first line of file2 could get slurped up by getline.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for long and good information.  If I needed 10 line, I would for sure use `grep -B 10 'something` file`. I am wear of most of the pitfall, but it good for all to read.  The use of `_` was just for fun :)

Comment: There's also the bug in the script as written that if the getline failed to read a line (e.g. it's at the end of the file) then you'd print the last line of the file twice. I'm sure there's other issues too and none of them obvious which is what makes it best not to suggest `getline` solutions unless it is THE right solution and/or you go through and list all of the caveats (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline) so the OP has a chance of understanding the risks in what APPEARS to be a simple solution.